# WebAPI project does not get pushed to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

For a personal coding project (an authentication/authorization back-end service) I am experiencing problems with pushing the code to a remote Git repo on Azure DevOps.

This is the situation:

- I have one solution, 'Auth', with three separate projects inside it: Auth.Core (with my models), Auth.Data (my DbContext and migration files) and Auth.WebAPI (with my controller, using the ASP.NET Core 3 API project template).
- I already deployed this app to Azure which is working fine
- In order to keep track of changes I want to add this project to an Azure DevOps repository, so I created a repository on Azure DevOps, cloned it to my local Dev computer
- I then copied all the solution files into that folder, made an initial commit and pushed it to Azure DevOps.

Here's the problem: somehow only my Auth.Core and Auth.Data files are pushed to DevOps, but my entire Auth.WebAPI project is missing. Instead on Azure DevOps I only see a 'Auth.WebAPI' file, instead of the complete folder.

[image]

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Here's a list of all the files inside the Auth.WebAPI folder:

[image]

Comment: The icon next to Auth.WebApi looks like a git icon, meaning that the folder is a separate repo.  Go into Auth.WebApi and see if there is a .git folder and deleted it f you want all projects u der the one solution repo.

Comment: Hmm, no there isn't a .git folder. I will add a screenshot of all the files in the Auth.WebAPI folder.

Comment: Not sure.  For some reason, it seams that Azure is seeing Auth.WebAPI is being picked up as a separate repository.  If you have git bash installed try navigatind to the Auth.WebAPI fold and do an `ls -la` and see if the `.git` folder shows up there.

Comment: Indeed there is a `.git` folder inside the `Auth.WebAPI` folder. Deleted it, then did another commit but same result, the complete WebAPI folder is neglected.

Comment: After a second try it worked with a new repository. Don't know why but the presence of the `.git` folder caused it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>My guess is that you pushed a branch other than `master`.</s>

My 2nd guess is that you pushed your WebApi folder including `.git` folder inside. Delete `.git` from the subfolder if you want to integrate `WebApi` into the main repo.

`.git` is a hidden folder so you have to work extra hard to see it:

[image]

Comment: No, I only have a `master` branch so that can't be the problem.

Comment: No .git folder inside the `WebAPI` folder.

Comment: `.git` is a hidden folder. Can you see `.git` in your main folder?

Comment: No there isn’t a .git folder visible inside root folder of the solution either

Comment: At the moment can’t check if there’s a hidden one.

Comment: Enable "Hidden files"

Comment: There was a `.git` folder inside WebAPI, deleted it but it has no effect.

Comment: Gave it another try, with setting up a new repo, cloning to local, copying all project files into it and deleting the `.git` folder and now it works. All three projects are pushed to Azure DevOps. Thanks!